# yum proxy error HTTP redirect

Tags: centos, proxy, yum

I've a VM running Centos 5.5 and I'm trying to get yum to update via a company proxy.

I can browse the web within the VM using the proxy setting , but I cannot get yum to use the proxy.

I'm getting the following error:

```
[Errno 14] HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error
that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Found
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

I've setup the proxy=http://my-proxy:8080/ and proxy_username= and proxy_password= in my /etc/yum.conf to the same values I'm using in firefox on the VM - which is working.

/etc/yum.repos.d has not been changed.

The proxy presents a web page upon initial 1st use of the proxy, asking for username and password. I think this could be causing the issue, is there any way yum can deal with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it sounds like your company is running a captive portal this will be quite an issue.

If you log on to the captive portal are you then able to use the proxy normally, or do you have to keep that portal session active?